# padrino can't find active_support methods

Tags: time, padrino, activesupport

In my Padrino application i'm trying to get the time 10 years from now using

> 10.year.from_now

I'm getting:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `year' for 10:Fixnum

Any idea why ?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveSupport is not fully loaded by default this because differently than rails Padrino aims to be small and fast.

If you use ActiveRecord a full set of ActiveSupport will be loaded otherwise you need to require (i.e. in boot.rb) your dependencies. In your case:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext'
require 'active_support/duration'
```

My suggestion is to load a full active_support set whenever is really needed.